# In yocto, is Variables such as RDEPENDS:${PN} and FILES:${PN} related to OVERRIDES?

Tags: yocto

I want to know exactly about the role of `:` between variables and `PN`.

I understand that it is related to `OVERRIDES` variables and if the value after `:` was in `OVERRIDES`, the variables will be selected.

If so, how can I think  variables like `RDEPENDS:${PN}` and `FILES:${PN}` ?

When I check `OVERRIDES` by `bitbake -e`, it shows the value as:

```bash
OVERRIDES="runtime-gnu:toolchain-gcc:linux:aarch64:pn-XXXX
```

but I cant't find `${PN}` in that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `OVERRIDES` as a feature that you can use to conditionally assign values to variables.

**Example**:

If you have a recipe that can work on various machines, and for each machine you have to select one specific file only:

List of machines you have:

- `machine1` needs `file1`
- `machine2` needs `file2`

Now in your `recipes.bb`

```bash
SRC_URI:append:machine1 = " file1"
SRC_URI:append:machine2 = " file2"
```

Now, since your machine is automatically exist in `OVERRIDES`variable, `Bitbake` will, at the end of the parsing process, override the variable with the value that is only compatible with the current machine.

So, if your `MACHINE = "machine1"`, `SRC_URI` will be appended with `file1`.

- The `PN` variable:

`OVERRIDES` variable contains `pn-${PN}` and not `${PN}`, and this is useful for recipes only if you want to set a varible with a value that is only related to that recipe and not any other recipe.

Actually, this is not useful inside the recipe itself:

Let's assume we have a variable called `DEMO_OVERRIDE` in a recipe called `recipe`:

```bash
DEMO_OVERRIDE:pn-${PN} = "${PN}"
```

Now, in `local.conf` we set a default value for it:

```bash
DEMO_OVERRIDE = "default_value"
```

Now, `bitbake -e | grep ^DEMO_OVERRIDE` will give: `default_value`, but:

`bitbake -e <recipe> | grep ^DEMO_OVERRIDE` will give `recipe`.

This is useful when you want to change a variable of a recipe from a `.conf` file like following:

```bash
SRC_URI:append:pn-<recipe> = " <value>"
```

- Regarding `RPROVIDES` and `FILES`:

The specification of `PN` with these variables are only used to split the package list to created at the end of the packaging task. Generally used in `do_package_split` and other tasks like following:

```py
d.getVar('FILES:' + pkg)

...

d.getVar('RPROVIDES:' + pkg)
```

and `pkg` is from: `PACKAGES` variable.

- For general overview about `OVERRIDES` check [this](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=overrides#term-OVERRIDES) link.
- For detailed overview about `OVERRIDES` check [this](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/2.4/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-metadata.html#conditional-syntax-overrides) link.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . It helped me understand yocto OVERRIDES  concept. Anyway, the ":" after FILES,RDEPENDS,RPROVIDES is not related to OVERRIDES and FILES:${PN} is a varialbe, right?

Comment: `VAR:${PN}` is a simple variable, VAR could be `FILES`, `RDEPENDS` or other.

Answer (score 1):

The ':' in FILES and RDEPENDS variables is related to OVERRIDES. In this case some code accesses the variable names directly (e.g. FILES:${PN}) and some sets OVERRIDES to include PN and then accesses FILES.

Looking through the code, you can see places where this happens during packaging:

```
meta/classes-global/package_rpm.bbclass:
localdata.setVar('OVERRIDES', d.getVar("OVERRIDES", False) + ":" + pkg)

meta/classes-global/package_ipk.bbclass:
localdata.setVar('OVERRIDES', d.getVar("OVERRIDES", False) + ":" + pkg) 

meta/classes-global/package.bbclass:
localdata.setVar('OVERRIDES', p)

meta/classes-global/package_deb.bbclass:
localdata.setVar('OVERRIDES', d.getVar("OVERRIDES", False) + ":" + pkg)
```

The reason ${PN} isn't there by default is that usually this is changed in a loop as it is iterated over. Each of the values in PACKAGES will be used. pn-${PN} is there by default as it is effectively a recipe override, not a package level override.